# Change color of text inside a div, when hovering a div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a div and a text inside of it. When I hover over the div, the div goes to a color in the right way. I would like the same for the text inside, but the code below doesn't work..

```
<div class="project-container">
  <div class="info" id="{{ product.id }}" data-color='#{{ product.color }}' data-transparencia='{{ product.transparencia }}'>
    <p class="info-texto">{{ product.texto }}</p>
  </div>
</div>

$(".info").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor:$(this).data('color'), opacity: $(this).data('transparencia') },30);
    },function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor:'transparent'},30);
    },function() {
        $('.info-texto').stop().animate({ color: "#FFFFFF" },30);
    }
);
```

Comment: Provide a fiddle please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method takes only two arguments, so try

```
$(".info").hover(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: $(this).data('color'),
        opacity: $(this).data('transparencia')
    }, 30);
    $(this).find('.info-texto').stop().animate({
        color: "#FFFFFF"
    }, 30);
}, function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    }, 30);
    $(this).find('.info-texto').stop().animate({
        color: ""
    }, 30);
});
```